# GridLayout rowSpan unexpected behavior. How it works?

Tags: android, gridview, grid-layout

I have the following design for a gridLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button android:text="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_rowSpan="2"
        android:text="2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_rowSpan="3"
        android:text="3" />

    <Button
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_rowSpan="2"
        android:text="4" />

    <Button
        android:text="5" />

    <Button
        android:text="6" />

    <Button
        android:text="7" />

    <Button
        android:text="8" />

    <Button
        android:text="9" />

</GridLayout>
```

And this is what I get:

[image: got design for gridview]

But this is what I want:

[image]

What could be happening? Why is that? Can I do what I want to do with a gridLayout?
(This was just an example to learn how to use this kind of layout)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `GridLayout` has nothing to define the height of the second row; it ends up being height 0dp. You can fix this by adding a column of views, each one row high, with `android:layout_width="0dp"`, height the same as one of your single-row views, and no gravity. They won't take up any visible part of the layout but they will force the rows to each have a non-zero height.